# how to get the response back to javascript from php using json?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN SOLVED**

**THE BELOW CODE IS THE CORRECTED AND WORKING CODE**

I have created a html form which sends certain variables to a php file and returns the success through json back to the javascript. But the problem is am not able to get any response back to the javascript file. I donno what is the reason. So can some help me with this. Thank you

my form is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script src="scriptj.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/donotdel/process.php" method="POST">
    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my javascript file is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.help-block').remove();
        var formData = {
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/donotdel/process.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (!data.success) {
                if (data.errors.name) {
                    $('#name-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.email) {
                    $('#email-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }
            }
            else {
                $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and my php file is

```
<?php

$errors         = array();      
$data           = array(); 

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if ( ! empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

the error that i am getting is instead of passing the json to javascript file, the json is printed in the screen. But whereas i need the javascript to show an alert.

Comment: put `die();` after `echo json_encode($data)`;   open browser console to check response.

Comment: Of course it's adding it to the page, that's what you're telling it to do using `append`. If all you want is to alert the json just replace everything in the `.done` function with `alert(data);`.

Comment: @Styphon  alert(data) will display only  [object][object]  in alert box ? not value rite?

Comment: @Susan Williams did you tried what i tell?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh using return won't change a thing.

Comment: To be honest it really isn't clear what your problem is. What does `json is printed in the screen` mean?

Comment: @Styphon  i ask him to check in browser console .. that is the area where you can read json objects

Comment: @charlietfl the json which has to be passed to javascript back is being printed instead of the alert that i want to show

Comment: So why are you not using code for alert? Also your subject implies a completely different problem. Question is even less clear now

Comment: @charlietfl if i get the response oly then i can show a alert.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the proper header in php:

```
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Failing that - can you post a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: What output does the `console.log(data);` give you?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
scriptj.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @SusanWilliams  here it means jquery library not loading . download jquery library  to you local file system and check

Comment: now im getting this error **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/donotdel/process.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.** in the consol

Comment: @SusanWilliams  now you can add  header ('Content-Type: application/json');  to php page as mention in answer

Comment: `header ('Content-Type: application/json');header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ` add above 2 lines above echo json_encode($data);  or top of php page

Comment: @SusanWilliams i have updated your issue in my answer

Answer (score 1):

As discussed with OP.

> -> First error is jQuery library not loaded from goole server so suggest to download latest jQuery library
>
> -> second error is `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`. suggest to add `header ('Content-Type:
>   application/json');header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in php
>   file or make sure to call ajax request from same origin domain

```
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo json_encode($data);
```